# CodeIgniter. Download Helper. Memory usage question

Tags: php, codeigniter

Question about this helper http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

If, for example, program.exe weights 4 GB, will it take a lot of PHP memory for reading and delivering that file?

```
$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/program.exe"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'software.exe';

force_download($name, $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`force_download` function just set the proper HTTP headers to make the client's browser download the file. So, it won't open the file, just pass it's URL to the client.

Check the helper source code, if you need: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/31b5c1dcf2ed/system/helpers/download_helper.php

**Edit:** I'd sugest creating your own version of the helper, and, instead of using `strlen` to get the file size, use the php function `filesize`, which takes only the file name as argument and returns the size in bytes.

More info, at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 1):

Yea... that could get... bad...

`file_get_contents` reads the entire contents of a file into a string. For large files, that can get, well, bad. I would look into [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).  Please remember too -- since CI automatically caches when you are loading a view, that means there will be no discernible benefit to readfile if it is used in a CI view. It would almost be better to handle this with an external script or by outputting directly from the controller and not calling the view at all.

Comment: +1 for poiting about the file size. I hadn't noticed that issue.